# insert NULL if input value is empty in C# to SQL server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert some values to database by using SQL command how if it has some column with empty, So it should indicate as 'NULL' value and rest view with actual values.

I tried with this query but it didn't work

```
    insert into details values NULLIF('SomeRecord','') AS [Null]
```

Comment: `UPDATE tablename SET columnname = newvalue WHERE columnname IS NULL`

Comment: I need to write INSERT Query

Comment: How come? INSERT is used to insert new rows, UPDATE is used to modify already existing rows.

Comment: Show the code the produces this `insert` statement.

Comment: "it didn't work" - how not? what happened? why is that wrong? what is `'SomeRecord'` meant to be, a value or a column? what is the schema's table, and some example input data and output results for empty/nonempty inputs?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, before and after your insert. (As formatted text, not images.) a.k.a. [mcve].

Comment: INSERT INTO bookstock VALUES ('Novel','NV-00002','Borrowable', ' ','Book_1','NV - 00002 - Book_1') this has empty place. its column name 'author'  .  'SomeRecord' mean a VALUE

Answer (score -1):

You want to insert a null column value. if string is empty? Not insert null column name.
I'd think you should be able to use the `CASE WHEN` feature to do what you want.

Perhaps something like this?

```
INSERT INTO details VALUES (CASE WHEN LEN(stringCol) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE stringCol END);
```

Assuming you want to set details.stringCol to the specified value, or null if empty.

Comment: Do you realise that's what `NULLIF()` does in the OP's example?  Also, you can't pass a column name as a parameter in your example, `stringCol` should be a literal value or query parameter.

Comment: this is my query : INSERT INTO bookstock  VALUES  ('Novel','NV-00002','Borrowable',    '   ','Book_1','NV - 00002 - Book_1')  this has empty place. its column name 'author'.

Comment: Please can you explain what is the clause 'NULLIF()'?